# C# - WPF how to get object layer level

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**My goal is :** Only allowed click to remove a rectangle if there is no rectangle in front of the target rectangle.
Maybe there is a solution to get a layer level from an object ? I have found nothing about this, im new to WPF. So if some can explain the solution or the way to think about this problem.

---

**Code xaml.cs file:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer gameTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        List<Rectangle> removeThis = new List<Rectangle>();

        int posX;
        int posY;
        int width;
        int rectangleVariation;
        int height;

        Random rand = new Random();
        Brush brush;


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Random rand = new Random();
            int nbObjects = rand.Next(15,30);

            for (int i = 0; i < nbObjects; i++)
            {
                brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)rand.Next(1, 255), (byte)rand.Next(1, 255), (byte)rand.Next(1, 255)));
                posX = rand.Next(15, 700);
                posY = rand.Next(50, 250);
                rectangleVariation = rand.Next(0, 2);

                if (rectangleVariation == 0)
                {
                    width = 200;
                    height = 50;
                }

                else
                {
                    width = 50;
                    height = 200;
                }

                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle
                {
                    Tag = "rectangle",
                    Height = height,
                    Width = width,
                    Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    Fill = brush
                };

                Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, posX);
                Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, posY);

                MyCanvas.Children.Add(rectangle);
            }
        }

        private void ClickOnCanvas(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource is Rectangle)
            {
                Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle)e.OriginalSource;
                MyCanvas.Children.Remove(rectangle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code xaml file :**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Canvas Name="MyCanvas" MouseLeftButtonDown="ClickOnCanvas" Background="DarkGray">
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: Without `Panel.ZIndex` being set on the Rectangles, stacking order is determined by the order of the elements in the Children collection. Use e.g. `MyCanvas.Children.IndexOf(rectangle)`.

Comment: Ok but how do I can use it to look if there is an other rectangle in front of this rectangle ?

Comment: You know the size and location of each Rectangle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first determine whether the clicked `Rectangle` intersects with any other `Rectangle` elements and if it does, you could determine whether it's in top of all of them by looking at the index in the `Canvas`'s `Children` collection.

The `Rect` type has an `IntersectsWith` method that you can use. Something like this:

```
private void ClickOnCanvas(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is Rectangle)
    {
        Rectangle clickedRectangle = (Rectangle)e.OriginalSource;
        Rect clickedRect = new Rect()
        {
            Location = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(clickedRectangle), Canvas.GetTop(clickedRectangle)),
            Size = new Size(clickedRectangle.Width, clickedRectangle.Height)
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < MyCanvas.Children.Count; i++)
        {
            if (MyCanvas.Children[i] is Rectangle rectangle && rectangle != clickedRectangle)
            {
                Rect rect = new Rect()
                {
                    Location = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(rectangle), Canvas.GetTop(rectangle)),
                    Size = new Size(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height)
                };
                if (clickedRect.IntersectsWith(rect) && MyCanvas.Children.IndexOf(clickedRectangle) < i)
                    return;
            }
        }

        MyCanvas.Children.Remove(clickedRectangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Super ! Thank you very much :)